# How to filter Graph API results ("with" modifier?)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to filter the results to get for instance only the ones that have the message field not null, here is the base url:
https://graph.facebook.com/[page id]/feed?access_token=[token]

How to filter?
How does the "with" modifier work? (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)
The doc is either extremely poor or well hidden.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer? I am currently facing the same problem.

Comment: It's been a while, I don't remember very well, I think I gave up ;-)

Comment: Mhh, too bad. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `with` parameter is used for location `with=location`. There is no filter in this endpoint to remove when the message field is not null.